# JavaScript - не меняются стили css

Tags: javascript, css, стилизация

**CSS**:

```
.noentering, .entering {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<h1 class="noentering">Вы не зашли на сайт.</h1>
<div class="entering">
    <p>Здравствуйте, <span class="nameofyou"></span>!</p>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var name;
if (confirm("Зайти на сайт?")) {
  name = prompt("Введите свое имя для продолжения");
  alert("Здравствуйте, " + name + "!");
  document.getElementsByClassName('entering').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('nameofyou').innerHTML(name);
} else {
  document.getElementsByClassName('noentering').style.display = 'block';
}
```

При нажатии в окне `confirm` на "отмену" или "ОК" `display: block` элементам не применяется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let name;
if (confirm("Зайти на сайт?")) {
  name = prompt("Введите свое имя для продолжения");
  alert("Здравствуйте, " + name + "!");
  document.querySelector('.entering').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.nameofyou').innerHTML = name;
} else {
  document.querySelector('.noentering').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.noentering, .entering {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="noentering">Вы не зашли на сайт.</h1>
<div class="entering">
    <p>Здравствуйте, <span class="nameofyou"></span>!</p>
</div>
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не отдельный элемент. Для этого нужно использовать `document.querySelector(selector)` + `innerHTML` - это св-во, а не функция